# Xamarin Android Zxing result parsing from QR code User name and Password

Tags: parsing, xamarin, qr-code, zxing

Hey Hello from Germany,

I'm trying with Zxing QR code result parsing. I have QR code with Username and Password and they will be used for Networkcredential by login any SOAP service.

How can I parsing a QR code Datamatrix with Xamarin.Android

I have already tried some method and class no funktion.[This my QR code from Navision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjkA5.png)

Comment: Hello back from Germany. ;-)
Zxing returns a string back to you if the QR code could be scanned. After that it is up to you how you parse the result.

One thing to mention. Authentication through QR code seem not like the smartest idea.

Comment: I know this idea is not smartest but I should do  it for a while on an Android Cell Phone or Scanner. Thank you.

Comment: So your question is answered? Should I convert my comment into an answer so you can mark it as a solution to your problem?